# How to replace a letter by mouseover with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I just wondered how I could change every `o` to a  by mouseover. How is it possible to do that?

```js
var o = 'o';

$(o).mouseover(function() {
  $(this).textContent = "";
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: tomato;
  position: relative;
}

article {
  transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(45deg);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 4vw;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section>
  <article>Like this post if you like cookies</article>
</section>
```

Comment: css would be your friend

Comment: @DanielA.White Don't you think the cookies tag was funny? And you would solve it only with css? Well, temporary with a hover function, it makes sense. But would it also be possible to let the cookies stay with CSS only?

Comment: jQuery selectors select elements, so the code in the question selects all of the `o` elements, of which there are none. If you replaced all of the "o"s in the text with `<o>o</o>`, that code might work. It would be invalid HTML, but it would work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of doing it...

I'm using jQuery to manipulate the `<p>` tags.  I take the original text and store it in a `data:text` attribute on that element so there won't be a need to undo any changes to the text.  Then the text is changed and updated within that element.

Then when the mouse moves out of the element, it then restores the original text, and then deletes the temporary `data:text` attribute.

```js
$("p").mouseover(function() {
  var el = $(this);
  var text = el.text();
  el.attr("data:text", text);
  
  el.text( 
      text.replaceAll( "o", "")
          .replaceAll( "t", "₸" )
          .replaceAll( "a", "ꋫ" ));
});
$("p").mouseout( function() {
  var el = $(this);
  var text = el.attr("data:text");
  el.removeAttr("data:text");
  
  if ( text && text.length > 0 ) {
    el.text( text );
  }
});

String.prototype.replaceAll = function( search, replace ) {
    var results = this.split(search).join(replace);

    return results;
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: tomato;
  position: relative;
}

article {
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(35deg);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 4vw;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section>
  <article>
    <p>Like this post if you like cookies</p>
    <br />
    <p>Here is more text to explore.</p>
    <br />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>
  </article>
</section>
```